# Retrain only Top Layer in Keras AlexNet

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, keras

I'm still pretty new to Keras/Theano, so please bear with me. But after googling and reading documentation, I did not find anything (except writing your own optimizer)

I've downloaded the convnets from https://github.com/heuritech/convnets-keras and here I wanted to use and retrain the AlexNet. I just want to retrain the top layers (dense 1,2,3) for 8 classes instead of 1000, so it would retain the "concepts" of images in the conv layers but generate output on my data (8 classes).

Is it somehow possible to set learning only for the top layers, e.g. freeze the bottom layers?

Thanks

Comment: you want to freeze the weights, see https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/622 for some hints on how to do this

Comment: Recent blog post is also very useful for this: http://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html

Comment: Thank you andyandy. If you would post that comments as a reply I will mark it as the Answer!